# Paypal subscription with nice interface

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have been trying to use paypal subscription and after redirect to paypal the interface were more or less like this (actually the subscription interface don't show prices only description)
[image]

After subscribe to a mockup app using Paypal, their developers manage some how to customize the interface like this

[image]I was checking my profile in paypal looking for some trick, but there is not trick (at least that I could detect), I have a regular Paypal subscription

Any idea how to make something like this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the "old" PayPal checkout pages vs. the "new".  They have been split testing these for a while now, so sometimes you will see one and other times you will see the other.